# How to validate forms in old browsers?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I need a way to validate a form in new and old browsers.

This is my code:

```
<form name="myForm">
    <input type="text" name="contactname" placeholder="Name" required>
    <input type="email" name="contactemail" placeholder="Email" required>  
    <input type="number" name="contactphone" placeholder="Phone Number" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57'>  
    <button type="submit">SEND</button>
</form>
```

This code works well in browsers that support HTML5, but it doesn't work in old browsers like internet explorer 8.
So I tried to add `onclick="validateform()"` in the submit button:

```
function validateform() {
    // Support for old browsers
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["contactname"].value;
    // if z is filled

    var y = document.forms["myForm"]["contactemail"].value;
    // if y is an email and it is filled

    var z = document.forms["myForm"]["contactphone"].value;
    // if z is a number
}
```

But then in the new browser it validates 2 times and it's annoying.
So what is the correct way to implement validation that supports old browsers?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=form+validation+polyfill

Comment: yep, a polyfill in these kind of circumstances is, in my opinion, the best solution. That way you're using the latest w3c stuff, regardless of which browser your app is running.

Comment: What is a good polyfill library ?

Comment: you can stick to JS validation only, this will work in all browsers..

Answer (score 1):

Check if browser supports HTML5 form validation or not then validate :

`typeof document.forms["myForm"]["contactname"].checkValidity == 'function'`

IF true then no need to validate(browser supports validation) else validate.

Answer (score 0):

If browser not supports HTML5 form validation then validate from jQuery see the demo - [Jquery validation demo](http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/)